# Insert Hyperlink in Access Database (pyodbc)

Tags: python-3.x, ms-access, hyperlink, pyodbc

Here is the situation: I'm 'having fun' really using Microsoft Access for the first time for small personnal project/tools ideas.

I don't know anything about VBA yet, and unless I can't do without it, I don't plan to learn it this time (already a lot else to cover).

So I tried to use Python to automatize the main table filling. I did find *pyodbc* package and succeeded to connect, read and write some data out of my database.
However, I wanted to experiment a little further, and one of the fields could contain hyperlinks (could be handled somewhere else in another script later, but I am curious about the functionality anyway)...

But I couldn't figure how to insert hyperlink data in the table. I only get the displayed text set, but not the target one.

Is this feasible using pyodbc or am I on the wrong track?

Thanks in advance!

Emmanuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyperlink field in MS Access consists of three parts, separated by `#`:

```
display text # filename or target # location within the document
```

So an example of the data of a field can look like this:

```
StackOverflow#http://www.stackoverflow.com#
```

See the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.hyperlinkpart

and samples here also: http://allenbrowne.com/casu-09.html